# Using Openlayers I can not generate the POST request correctly

Tags: xml, post, openlayers

I am trying to make a post request using OpenLayers library. Here is part of my code that I have:

```
         OpenLayers.Request.POST({
               url: this.url,
               scope: this,
               success: this.drawChart,
               failure: function() {
               this.loadMask.hide();
               alert("No data for charts...")
                },
      data: xml2
    });
```

Where xml2 is:

```
              var xml2 = this.obsformat.write({
                   eventTime: 'first',
                   resultModel: 'om:Measurement',
                   responseMode: 'inline',
                   procedure: station,
                   offering: phenom,
           observedProperties: obsprop,
                   responseFormat: this.responseFormat

                });
```

In xml2:  phenom and obsprop are string variables that I get from some dropdown menus.
The variables are equal to:

```
          phenom = 'Climate'
          obsprop = 'fdgf'
```

Using firebug I found out that my POST request looks like this:

```
 <GetObservation xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sos/1.0" version="1.0.0" service="SOS" xmlns:om="http://www.opengis.net/om/1.0" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sos/1.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/sos/1.0.0/sosGetObservation.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <offering>Climate</offering>
 <eventTime>
 <ogc:TM_During>
 <ogc:PropertyName>om:samplingTime</ogc:PropertyName>
 <gml:TimePeriod>
 <gml:beginPosition>2013-07-04T00:30</gml:beginPosition>
 <gml:endPosition>2013-07-06T00:30</gml:endPosition>
 </gml:TimePeriod>
 </ogc:TM_During>
 </eventTime>
 <observedProperty>f</observedProperty>
 <observedProperty>d</observedProperty>
 <observedProperty>g</observedProperty>
 <observedProperty>f</observedProperty>
 <responseFormat>text/xml;subtype="OM/1.0.0"</responseFormat>
 <resultModel>om:Measurement</resultModel>
 <responseMode>inline</responseMode>
 </GetObservation>
```

For some reason the variable "obsprop" instead of being stored in one xml element  it is parsed in many different ones (see above). This doesn't happen with the other variables, which are also string types.

Does anyone can help me with this? It must be something simple but I can not find out what.

I hope my question is clear. Please let me know if I have to explain something better.

Thanks a lot
Dimitris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that in xml2, the value in `observedProperties` must be an object. What I have assigned (obsprop) was a string.

By assigning the string in an object it works perfectly:

```
ObservProp = {obsProp:obsprop}; // assign the string obsprop to a key

var xml2 = this.obsformat.write({
    eventTime: 'first',
    resultModel: 'om:Measurement',
    responseMode: 'inline',
    procedure: station,
    offering: phenom,
    observedProperties: ObservProp, // this is an object now
    responseFormat: this.responseFormat

});
```